# What is the correct way to get the "final" input value of an AutoComplete component in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, autocomplete

I've been getting "`Cannot update during state transition`" errors on my AutoComplete component, and after some searching around I found that it was because of my `renderInput` code.

I try to read the input during `renderInput`, but I can't edit the state then, so I can't read the input when I need to. It's all very confusing to me.

Is there a way to only execute a method when a value is really selected? EG when Enter is pressed when highlighting something, when an option in the popup is clicked, etc.

Below is the `renderInput` code:

```
public render() {
  const { classes } = this.props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.autoSuggest}>
      <Autocomplete
        ListboxProps={{ style: { maxHeight: 200, overflow: 'auto' } }}
        autoHighlight={true}
        disablePortal={false}
        options={this.getOptions()}
        onClick={(_event, value) => this.onSelect(value)}
        renderInput={(input) => { return this.onInput(input);}}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

private onInput(input: AutocompleteRenderInputParams) {
  if (!this.state.alleenUnCodes &&
      input.inputProps.value !== undefined &&
      input.inputProps.value.toString() !== "" &&
      input.inputProps.value.toString().charAt(0) === '/') {
    this.setState({alleenUnCodes: true});
  }

  if (this.state.alleenUnCodes &&
      input.inputProps.value !== undefined &&
      input.inputProps.value.toString().charAt(0) !== '/') {
    this.setState({alleenUnCodes: false});
  }

  return <TextField {...input} label={'Type GEVI/UN of /UN code (bv 20/1002, of /20)'}/>;
}
```

EDIT: I found the answer... I tried to read the input to filter my options. However, apparently I can just use the filterOptions param!

Comment: `isOptionEqualToValue` search for this once.

Comment: @AdeshKumar isOptionEqualToValue doesn't filter the options based on the input, which is what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had completely missed the `filterOptions` parameter despite reading the React AutoComplete documentation multiple times. It seems that for filtering the option filterOptions is the perfect option!

For those interested, the working code:

```
filterOptions={(options, state) => { 
            return options.filter((option) => { 
              return option.substring(0, state.inputValue.length) === state.inputValue;
            });
          }}
```

Answer (score 0):

you already have an **onSelect** method that is being called when the user clicks an option in the autocomplete list. You can use this method to update the state of your component with the selected value, and then use the updated state to render the final value.

```
private onSelect(value: any) {
  this.setState({ selectedValue: value });
}
```

**selectedValue** is a state variable that you can use to store the final input value.

you can also use the **onChange** method provided by the **renderInput** prop to listen to changes in the input value as the user types. You can then update the state with the current input value and use it to render the final value

```
private onInput(input: AutocompleteRenderInputParams) {
  this.setState({ inputValue: input.inputProps.value });

  // ... rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Your first example is what I originally had, but it gave me the described error. Your second example might work as well, but I feel like it isn't the best solution for my use case. The filterOptions parameter did exactly what I needed (namely, filter the options)